# Interact.js problems with Google Chrome v55

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, interact.js

We have been using interact.js for a while now in our angular web application. I recently updated google chrome to v55. Since this happened, I'm getting the following error in the console every time I enter the browser window (probably mouseenter event):

```
interact.js:637 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined
    at getXY (interact.js:637)
    at getPageXY (interact.js:654)
    at setEventXY (interact.js:598)
    at Interaction.setEventXY (interact.js:1307)
    at Interaction.pointerMove (interact.js:1757)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (interact.js:3307)
```

The error occurs regardless of wether we ever call interact(). I added outputs to every code line where we call interact() but even on pages where we do not call interact() a single time, the error comes up in the console log whenever the mouse enters the browser window.

I don't get this error in any other browser and I did not get it before I updated Google Chrome.

I tried changing the version of interact.js and found out that the error does not occur until v1.2.4 (latest version is 1.2.5).

Has anyone got the same or a similar problem and knows how to bypass this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out it is a known issue for interact.js and chrome v55:
https://github.com/taye/interact.js/issues/457